# How to separate this value from list

Tags: powershell, xslt, xpath, automation, servicenow

I am getting username value as sysid from servicenow form

[90b6ed4ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619e8,c7e6a18ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619cd] - these values represent sysid of two users

This list values can vary depending on users entered in the form. I need to separate each value by comma. So that I can use each user sysid individually to get the username of the user from his sysids.

Also as 2 values are mentioned above, it can also be only 1 or can be 10 or more depending on the users entered in servicenow form

Comment: This seems like a simple trim and split. Is there _anything_ you have tried? Whats with the extra tags? They do not seen pertinent to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to separate a string out is by using `Split()`. Also, if you want to take off the brackets around the string, you should use `Trim()`.

This should work for your example string of:

> [90b6ed4ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619e8,c7e6a18ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619cd]

Example:

```
$example = "[90b6ed4ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619e8,c7e6a18ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619cd]"

$example.Split(',').TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']')
```

You could go one step further and add the users to an array.

Example:

```
$example = "[90b6ed4ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619e8,c7e6a18ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619cd]"

[string[]]$users = $example.Split(',').TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']')
```

Comment: This would be a little cleaner `$example.Trim('[]').Split(',')`. Also, you should not need to force a string array.

Comment: @Matt I agree. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use a regex.

```
$s = [90b6ed4ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619e8,c7e6a18ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619cd]
$user1, $user2 = ($s -replace '\[(.*),(.*)\]$', '$1 $2').split()
```

Or, if you wanted an array...

```
$users = ($s -replace '\[(.*),(.*)\]$', '$1 $2').split()
```

Comment: This might not work in _all_ use cases but I think this might be a lot simpler `[regex]::Matches($s,"\w+").Value`

Answer (score 0):

`Select-String` would be another possible approach (assuming that the value you have actually *is* a string):

```
$s = '[90b6ed4ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619e8,c7e6a18ddbad9b445905ef92ca9619cd]'
($s | Select-String '[a-f0-9]+' -AllMatches).Matches.Groups.Value
```

The above code requires PowerShell v3 or newer, though. With older versions you'd need to expand the nested elements via `Select-Object`:

```
$s | Select-String '[a-f0-9]+' -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -Expand Groups |
    Select-Object -Expand Value
```